# How to use loop on backbone template when the data is loaded by AJAX?

Tags: ajax, json, backbone.js

one short question about this: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xczBy/

What if my Json is loaded by fetch()? **simple example**

```
var self = this;
this.collection.fetch({
      reset: true,
      success: function (model, attributes) {
                    self.render();
      }
});
```

I need to know how to set 'posts' in my loop template

```
    <% _.each(posts, function(post){ %>
         <span class="day"><%=posts.day %></span><br />
    <% }); %>
```

Comment: The fact that you're fetching the data won't change anything except that it's asynchronous. As you didn't miss that part, what could be your problem?

Comment: I have a problem with this part: var action = new Action(acs);
var actionView = new ActionView({model:action}); Where I sholud create this object action? I try in initialize() in view but didn't work :/

Comment: I'll assume your collection is a collection of actions so the actions will be created automatically. For the views, you could loop through the content of your collection and create a view for each action. Is it enough?